# How to see the whole portion of the Updated Content of a file

Tags: linux, logfiles

I have a application where the log files are being generated in a Linux Machine .

I want to monitor the application while it is in production , so when i used the tail command with the log file name , it only shows only a portion of the updated file .

The command i used is   `tail MyLog.log`

My question is , is it possible to see the whole latest Portion of the file which is updated? Any suggestions?

Comment: Define "updated portion", `tail -f` is a good answer tho and i +1'ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ***follow*** the growth of the file by using the `-f` option of tail:

```
tail -f MyLog.log
```

Comment: This is sufficient for me . Thank you codaddict ,blunderboy,tuxuday ,KurzedMetal

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can check only the latest updated portion. However you can check the n lines of file using -n flag and using -f flag this process repeats itself.

So you can use something like tail -f -n 10 Mylog.txt

You can read more about tail command at http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm

Comment: I like this anwer very much , but i am not sure of how many lines the o/p would be actually .

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in question with **less** and press **F**. This is akin to @codaddict solution